# How to add a gitlab file which contains multiple parameter entries to be scheduled in "Build periodically with parameters Schedule" jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, build, cron, scheduling

How to read the text line from a file?

option- File could be read from gitlab repo.

Either any other way for scheduling many times with different time and parameters.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get an idea, if we can provide a file path from GITLAB in "Build periodically with parameter" , instead of entering multiple cron trigger lines.